# Outlook email body and table looks stretched out in Windows vs Mac

Tags: html, css, html-table, fonts, border

I have a .hbs (Handlebars) file, which includes the css and html for an email with a body/message and a table.  In Mac, it looks as expected.  In Windows, it does not look correct and should mirror how it is looking in Mac.  Below is a snapshot in Windows, and another is a snapshot in Mac (correct view):

Mac:
[image]

Windows:
[image]

Below is the .hbs file contents:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>
  .New-User-Feedback {
      width: 640px;
        padding: 25px 33px 10px 28px;
    }

  .mj-column-per-100 {
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
  .Grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-bottom: 0px 0px 20px 24px;
  }

  .Grid-cell {
      flex: 1;
      margin-right: 16px;
  }
  
  
  .emailBody {
    width: 579px;
      margin: 20px 0 0;
      padding: 54px 29.5px 37px 29.5px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .Message-Body {
      width: 480px;
      height: 80px;
      margin: 39px 15px 29.5px 0.5px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.43;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      color: #161616;
  }
  .Message-Body .user-name {
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  
  table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  th,td {
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.43;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }

  th {
      width: 121px;
      padding: 14px 58px 14px 16px;
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #161616;
  }
  
  td {
    width: 400px;
      margin: 29.5px 23.5px 0 33.5px;
      padding: 0 0 0 16px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: #545454;
  }
  
  .End-Note {
    width: 56px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 15px 9px 0 0.5px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.43;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      color: #161616;
  }
    
</style>

<body style="font-family: helvetica; background-color: #f2f5fb; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
<div class="New-User-Feedback">
    <div class="emailBody">
      <div style="background:#DFDEDE;background-color:#DFDEDE;margin:0px auto;max-width:1000px;">
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#DFDEDE;background-color:#DFDEDE;width:100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;">
              <!--[if mso | IE]><table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:1000px;" ><![endif]-->
              <div class="mj-column-per-100 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                        <div style="font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:30px;font-weight:500;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#000000;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                          New Crystal Feedback</div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>  
                </table>
              </div>
              <!--[if mso | IE]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
        <span class="Message-Body" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>Hello <span class="user-name">{{team}}</span>,
            <br/>
            A new user feedback submitted for Crystal. 
            <br/>
            Kindly review the feedback details mentioned below and take neccessary action:</p>
        </span>
        <div class="New-User-Feedback-Info">
          <table>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <th> Priority </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.priority}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th> Summary </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.summary}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th> Description </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.description}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th> Type </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.type}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th> Business Impact </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.busImpact}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th> Reporter </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.reporter}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th> JIRA </th>
                        <td> {{feedbackData.jira}} </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
        <span class="End-Note">
          - My team
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there anything specific with any of the css properties that is causing it to look like the table is elongated and also not properly within the grid like we see on Mac?  Please let me know.  I'm fairly new with css so I'm not sure where to start or what the issue is.